# Load balancing for SSL server, NOT web server

Tags: ssl, twisted, load-balancing, haproxy

I'm finding it pretty difficult to get reliable information on Google about how exactly to do load balancing for anything other than a web server. Here is my situation: I currently have a python/twisted SSL server running on one machine. This is not fast enough so I want to change this so that multiple instances of this server will run on multiple machines behind a load balancer. So suppose I have two copies of this server process: TWISTED1 and TWISTED2. TWISTED1 will run on MACHINE1 and TWISTED2 will run on MACHINE2. Both TWISTED1 and TWISTED2 are SSL server processes. A separate machine LOAD_BALANCER is used to load balance between the two machines.

Where do I put my existing SSL certificate? Do I put an identical copy on both MACHINE1 and MACHINE2? Do I also have an identical copy on LOAD_BALANCER? I do NOT want unencrypted traffic between LOAD_BALANCER and MACHINE1 or MACHINE2, and also the twisted processes are already set up as SSL servers, so it would be unnecessary work to remove SSL from the twisted process. Basically I want to set up load balancing for SSL traffic with minimal changes to the existing twisted scripts. What is the solution?

Regarding the load balancer, is it sufficient to use another machine MACHINE3 and put HAPROXY onto this machine as the load balancer or is it better to use a hardware load balancer like Baracuda?

Note also that most of the connections to the twisted process are persistent connections.

Comment: With just two machines: Why not make live a little bit easier: Use a round robin DNS. Simple setup, no extra machines needed: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS for some more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Could you have the certs on one machine and a mount from the other machine to the machine w/ the certs? Allowing you to only have one set of ssl certs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with load balancing a [TLS](https://thoughtstreams.io/glyph/there-is-no-ssl/) server is that without [the HTTP "forwarded for" header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For), there's no way to tell where the original connection came from.  That's why so much documentation focuses on load-balancing HTTP(S).

You can configure TLS termination in more or less all of the ways that you've described; it sounds like you can simply have your load balancer act as a TCP load balancer.  The only reason to have your load balancer have your certificate (with the implication being that it also would have your private key) would be for it to decrypt the traffic to figure out what to do with it, then re-encrypt it to the machines.  If you don't need to do that, put the certificate only on the target machines and not on the LB.